# Dim str1 As String = "SELECT *FROM GET_A_USER_LOGIN (" + EMP_ID + ")"

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
 Dim str1 As String = "SELECT *FROM GET_A_USER_LOGIN (" + EMP_ID + ")"
```

I want to call the function in SQL Server, but I ge tan error

> Cannot convert string to decimal

For `EMP_ID` datatype is decimal

Comment: Yes, thats one of the many, many reason to use SQL Parameters rather than concatenating like that (you really use a Decimal for Id?).  Read [ask] and take the [tour], especially the part about a Good Title.

Comment: I believe if you want to call a **function** in SQL Server, you must use the **schema identifier** (and a **parametrized query!**) - try `SELECT * FROM dbo.Get_a_user_login(@EmpID);`

Answer (score 0):

Use parameterized queries:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM GET_A_USER_LOGIN (@EMPID)"

Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string here"), _
    cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EMPID", SqlDbType.Decimal , 18).Value = EMPID
    Return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()

End Using
```

Comment: Thank for your answer